# Cloud-init to configure an Ubuntu docker container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cloud-init

Is it possible to use a **cloud-init configuration file** to define commands to be executed when a docker container is started?

I'd like to test the provisioning of an Ubuntu virtual machine using a docker container.
My idea is to provide the same cloud-init config file to an Ubuntu docker container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If you want to test a VM setup, you need to use actual virtualization technology.  The VM and Docker runtime environments are extremely different and you can't just substitute one technology for the other.  A normal Linux VM startup will run a raft of daemons and startup scripts – systemd, crond, sshd, ifconfig, cloud-init, ... – but a Docker container will start *none* of these and will only run the single process in the container.

If your cloud-init script is ultimately running a `docker run` command, you can provide an alternate command to that container the same way you could `docker run` on your development system.  But a Docker container won't look to places like the EC2 metadata service to find its own configuration usually, and it'd be unusual for a container to run cloud-init at all.